# How to move whole icon OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I use the style icon:

```
const styleIcon = {
  anchorXUnits: "fraction",
  anchorYUnits: "pixels",
  crossOrigin: "anonymous",
  anchor: [0.5, 145],
  scale: 0.5,
  color: "#c5a368",
  src: "./assets/images/point.svg",
};
```

And the rest styles:

```
const test2 = [
      new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)",
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: "#143261",
          width: 2,
        }),
        image: new Icon({ ...styleIcon }),
      }),
});
```

Then I apply them for layers:

```
  this.vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.source,
      zIndex: 400,
      style: test2,
    });
```

As result I can move the pointer only by dot:

[image]

How to move icon by whole icon area?

Comment: See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-icon.html.